# How to join 2 column as 1 in SQL with some condition like description below

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel

I have 2 columns in `SQL Server` which I want to join as 1 in a C# console application.

Will contain the `Server Name (col A)` and `Instance Name (Col B)`, separated by a backslash (`\`).

If the instance column read from the database contains a backslash in the text (`\`), remove the backslash and everything to the left of it before combining the fields for the `SIN column` of the spreadsheet (`Excel`) (only truncate this for processing - nothing changes in the database).

For example, if the instance column contains

```
ANDSQLP47\CTOPROD8R2
```

then truncate that to `CTOPROD8R2` before combining it with the ServerName column.

Comment: That sounds like something you shouldn't be doing in SQL in the first place.

Comment: I can bringing Data from SQL and store in ECxel file through C# console Application

Comment: Can you share the SQL? are you using LINQ?

Comment: I found my Solution SELECT A + '\' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(B,'\','.'),

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

- First find the index of the first occurring of character "\" in the string
- Then use the left function to read from start upto the point of the index or substring
- Then finally concat it with the 2nd column

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want it in SQL it's also possible but I found my Solution                                   SELECT A + '\' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(B,'\','.'), 1) FROM yourTable          Thank You very Much

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
SELECT A + '\' + PARSENAME(REPLACE(B,'\','.'), 1) FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Its working on SQL but when I put in C# in showing repitition                      SELECT [ServerName]+ '\' + PARSENAME(REPLACE([Instance],'\','.'),1) AS SIN,DBName,Loginname,AccountType,ComplexityCheck,ExpirationCheck,ManualCheck,Accesstype,SecFormReq,SecFormArc,DATE FROM [DBReports].[dbo].[Accesslevelreport]                                                      SQL Output  =   601SQLM07\JHUSAFMOD08                                     C# Output in excel=   601SQLM07601SQLM07\JHUSAFMOD08

Comment: C# query=                                                                                                        string query = " SELECT [ServerName]+ '\' + PARSENAME(REPLACE([Instance],'\','.'), 1) AS SIN,DBName,Loginname,AccountType,ComplexityCheck,ExpirationCheck,ManualCheck,Accesstype,SecFormReq,SecFormArc,DATE FROM [DBReports].[dbo].[Accesslevelreport] WHERE DATE >= '" + startDate + "' AND DATE <= '" + endDate + "'";

Comment: @Asim in c# some strings may be sensitive to special characters like "\".

Comment: yes adding @ before string solved the problem Thank You very much !!